# What creating bootloop when flashing TWRP?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, bootloader, samsung-galaxy-j2

I follow this XDA tutorial to [flash TWRP and rooting Samsung Galaxy J250F](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-root-twrp-3-2-x-galaxy-j2-pro-2018-sm-j250f.3796658/). However, after flashing TWRP via Odin, the phone only boots into recovery, not system. Even factory reset or [empty the misc partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189068/94084#232352) cannot help. I have to reflash its [stock ROM](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-j2-pro/firmware/SM-J250F/XXV/download/J250FDXS2ASH2/292693/). This erases TWRP and replace with the stock recovery.

This is what the tutorial says, which I follow exactly:

> Flash with ODIN in the AP slot.
> Put your device in DOWNLOAD mode.
> Uncheck Auto reboot.
> Load the respective file below into the AP slot and hit start.
> After flashing and ODIN reports PASS immediately reboot to recovery by holding POWER + HOME + VOL DOWN.
> As soon as the screen goes blank change to VOL UP whilst still holding POWER + HOME.
> You should now see TWRP recovery.

Yes I see TWRP recovery, but now the system cannot be booted.

Comment: I assume you have read the section IMPORTANT about  dm-verity?

Comment: 1. In Odin did you unselected reboot option 2.How did try to boot into system after installing TWRP? Power buttons or through TWRP - boot - system

Comment: @alecxs man, the way the article is structured made me think that that section is not important until installing TWRP is done. I had had an incorrect expectation that installing TWRP shouldn't create bootloop 

Comment: @beeshyams 1 yes. (Actually in the first attempt I didn't, but the result seems to be the same.) 2 Via TWRP

Comment: Thank you everyone for supporting me. [I suggest the OP to write a better post here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-root-twrp-3-2-x-galaxy-j2-pro-2018-sm-j250f.3796658/page-3#post-84186563)

Comment: consider in (xda) developers scene it is common sense to disable dm-verity when mess with partitions, therefore you are lucky when you even find a hint about dm-verity at all. also please note that xda has changed forum software recently and all posts became ugly (one should change dark mode to xda classic to make it look like old forum for better readability)